# WPF DataGrid ComboBoxColum with same dynamic content for each row

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In a `DataGrid`, I want a `ComboBoxColumn` that has the same content for each row. The content of the `ComboBox` is dynamic: if you select a value in the `ComboBox` for a row, this selected value must not be selectable for the other rows. My current problem is that the content of the `ComboBox` is not updated in the previous lines. I made a simple example to explain it:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              Height="auto"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Key" MinWidth="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.KeyList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Findancestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsSelectable}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="80" Content="Add Row" Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**MAIN VM**

```
public class MainVM
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemsVM> myItems;

    private List<Key> myKeyList = new List<Key>()
    {
        new Key("Item 1", true),
        new Key("Item 2", true),
        new Key("Item 3", true)
        
    };

    public MainVM()
    {
        myItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemsVM>();

        AddRowCommandAction();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemsVM> Items => myItems;
    public ItemsVM SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public List<Key> KeyList => myKeyList;

    private void SetKeySelectability()
    {
        foreach (Key item in myKeyList)
        {
            if (myItems.Any(x => x.SelectedKey == item))
                item.IsSelectable = false;
            else
                item.IsSelectable = true;
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand myAddRowCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddRowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (myAddRowCommand == null)
                myAddRowCommand = new RelayCommand(AddRowCommandAction);

            return myAddRowCommand;
        }
    }

    private void AddRowCommandAction()
    {
        myItems.Add(new ItemsVM
        { 
            Value = string.Format("Row {0}", myItems.Count + 1),
            SelectedKey = myKeyList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelectable == true)
        });

        SetKeySelectability();
    }
}
```

**OTHER CLASSES**

```
public class ItemsVM
{ 
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Key SelectedKey { get; set; }
}

public class Key : ObservableObject
{
    private bool _IsSelectable;

    public Key(string name, bool isselectable)
    { 
        Name = name;
        IsSelectable = isselectable;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelectable
    { 
        get { return _IsSelectable; } 
        set
        {
            if (_IsSelectable == value) return;
            
            _IsSelectable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectable));
        }
    }
}
```

At start, we can see as the `Item 1` is selected for the `Row 1`, `Item 1` `IsSelectable` property is updated and is not selectable anymore:

[image]

After cliked the `Button` to add a row, I get this (which is correct). The two used values are not selectable and the `Row 1's` `ComboBox` has the same value.

[image]

Now, I change the value for the `Row 1`: We can see that the `Item 1` is not selectable (but it should be) and the `Row 2's` `ComboBox` is not up to date either (`Item 3` is selectable and should not and `Item 1` is not released)

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in order to achieve this, you need to update the **IsSelectable** property of the **Key** instances when a ComboBox's selected item changes.

In your case, you need to raise the **PropertyChanged** event from your **ItemsVM** class whenever **SelectedKey** changes. This is needed to notify the **MainVM** so it can update the **IsSelectable** properties of the Key instances.

Here is how you can do it:

1. Make ItemsVM class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class ItemsVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public string Value { get; set; }

    private Key _selectedKey;
    public Key SelectedKey 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _selectedKey;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedKey == value) return;
            _selectedKey = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedKey));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

2. In MainVM class, subscribe to PropertyChanged event of ItemsVM instances:

```
private void AddRowCommandAction()
{
    var newItem = new ItemsVM
    { 
        Value = string.Format("Row {0}", myItems.Count + 1),
        SelectedKey = myKeyList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelectable == true)
    };

    newItem.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
    myItems.Add(newItem);

    SetKeySelectability();
}
```

3. Add ItemPropertyChanged method to MainVM to handle the event:

```
private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ItemsVM.SelectedKey))
    {
        SetKeySelectability();
    }
}
```

4. Finally, unsubscribe from the PropertyChanged event when appropriate to avoid memory leaks. For example, you might remove ItemsVM instances from myItems at some point, and you need to unsubscribe before you do that:

```
private void RemoveItem(ItemsVM item)
{
    item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
    myItems.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As I'm using CommunityToolkitMvvm, no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, ObservableObject does the trick.